# Process data from the database in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my application, I have a collection called Messages. Defined as follows:

```
 var email = userEmail();
 var time = new Date().getTime();
 //value is the text of the message
 message = {user: Meteor.userId(), time: time, message: value};
 Messages.insert(message);
```

In my template, I have the following:

```
{{#each messages}}
     <li class="panel panel-default">
          <p class="date">{{time}}</p>
          <a href="http://{{message}}">{{message}}</a>
     </li>
{{/each}}
```

Of course, when I visit my webpage, it display the time as an epoch timestamp number, ex: 1398954569368

I want to process my `{{time}}` so it displays it in a human-readable format.

How or where can I access my `{{time}}` variable so I can do JavaScript operations on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is what Date().getTime() returns. Check out MDN on the Date object:

> Date.prototype.getTime() 
>   Returns the numeric value of the specified
>   date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC
>   (negative for prior times).

Date/Time objects can be accessed/modified using Moment.js within a Template helper, assuming your information is accessible via that route. So as an example:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.time = function() { 
    return moment(yourDateObject).fromNow();
};
```

[Meteor Template Helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers)

Comment: I know *how* to convert an epoch timestamp to a date. Note the last line: `How or where can I access my {{time}} variable so I can do JavaScript operations on it?`. And then especially, *where* I can access it

Comment: Apologies for missing that. You can access/modify it within a template helper, assuming your information is accessible via that route. So for example:  Template.yourTemplateName.time = function() {  return moment(yourDateObject).fromNow() };   http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers

Comment: Ah, helpers. It works now.

If you include this in your post, I will choose your answer as accepted.